# c# how to import a powershell module from a string

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm using c# and I want to use import-module to import a powershell script. However I don't want to have a .psm1 file on disk. I want to have it hardcoded on my code, like in a string and then import it.

Is that possible?

All the example I can find are something like:

```
pipeline.Commands.Add("Import-Module");
var command = pipeline.Commands[0];
command.Parameters.Add("Name", @"G:\PowerShell\PowerDbg.psm1")
```

or something like:

```
var ps = PowerShell.Create(myRS);
ps.Commands.AddCommand("Import-Module").AddArgument(@"g:\...\PowerDbg.psm1")
ps.Invoke()
```

However as I said above I don't want to read a file from disk. I want it hardcoded to avoid multiple files. I want everything on an exe and that's it. I couldn't find a way, any help is appreciated.

The reason I want to use import-module is because after importing the module I want to do something like:

```
get-command -module <whatever>
```

and get a list of all its functions.
Any other way to list functions from a script might be helpful too.

Thanks.

Comment: Somewhat related - check out [`PSExt` for WinDbg](https://github.com/powercode/PSExt) if you're looking at automating WinDbg

Comment: Sorry the PowerDbg was only a random example I copy pasted from another post. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for [`New-Module`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849740.aspx); it does exactly what you're asking for.

From the TechNet page (paraphrased):

```bsh
New-Module -ScriptBlock {
    $SayHelloHelp="Type 'SayHello', a space, and a name."
    function SayHello ($name) { 
        "Hello, $name" 
    } 
    Export-ModuleMember -function SayHello -Variable SayHelloHelp
} -Name PowerDbg
```

C# Example (not tested):

```cs
string moduleContents = @"...";
pipeline.Commands.Add("New-Module");
var command = pipeline.Commands[0];
command.Parameters.Add("ScriptBlock", moduleContents);
command.Parameters.Add("Name", "PowerDbg");
pipeline.Invoke();
```

Comment: great! the c# example doesn't work but I'll work around it. New-Module seems to be exactly what I need. Thanks.